# ReactJS How to style React Calendar

Tags: reactjs

Currently am using react-calendar library for my react application. I need show my calendar dates in a  month with different colors. Note we have use reactjs only. Here am attaching image and [react-calendar library link](http://%20%20https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar).

[image]

Comment: This is not a free code writing service. What have you tried? Please [edit]
your question (do *not* add comments) and provide your code as a [mcve].
What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead?
Include any error messages and stack traces.
You may want to take the [tour] to understand how to ask a good question.

Answer (score -1):

here is react calendar example:

https://reactjsexample.com/tag/calendar/

Comment: An answer to SO should never just consist of a link to an external resource. This could change or disappear over time.